# How to retrieve sql job execution datetime with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Just like in title, is it even possible to retrieve data regarding sql jobs? I'm particularly interested in the most recent execution datetime of specfied job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job history is in `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory`.

You can just create an entity class for querying that table and then query it through a DbContext connected to that database.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have 3 options:

- first: you can set in your sql cmd a field for date and log it
- second: install SQL Server Audit for logs
- third: install sql profiler that almost like sql audit